# Image conversion with GAE Image API

Tags: java, image, google-app-engine, image-processing

I'm trying to understand how to deal with GAE Image api, to automatically convert between image format to JPEG.

Here is my code:

```
byte[] oldImageData = model.getImage();
Image oldImage = ImagesServiceFactory.makeImage(oldImageData);
LOG.info("Image format - " + oldImage.getFormat().toString());
model.setImage(oldImage.getImageData()); // byte array must be JPEG
```

The `oldImageData` byte array here can be a byte array of a JPEG or PNG image, or worst case not an image.

- If the byte array is not image data what would the Exception my app
  needs to catch?
- If the byte array is image but the exact type is not known by my app,
  what should be done so that the GAE Image service will automatically
  convert it to JPEG.

Finally, what I need to do is to make sure that `oldImageData` is a byte array for a `JPEG` image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
Image oldImage = ImagesServiceFactory.makeImage(oldImageData);

// this throws an exception if data is not image or unsupported format
// you can wrap this in try..catch and act accordingly 
oldImage.getFormat();

// this is a dummy transform that does nothing
Transform transform = ImagesServiceFactory.makeCrop(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);

// setting the output to JPEG
OutputSettings outputSettings = new OutputSettings(ImagesService.OutputEncoding.JPEG);
outputSettings.setQuality(100);

// apply dummy transform and output settings
Image newImage = imagesService.applyTransform(transform, oldImage, outputSettings);

byte[] newImageData = newImage.getImageData();
```

Comment: Same problem here: colors get distorted when converting from PNG to JPEG on the dev server (1.9.17). On the production server the colors seem to be fine, though. Example: colors in [this wikipedia PNG image](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png) with alpha layer are fine when converted to JPEG, only the background gets turned black.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `magic number` of any image and based on that you can take action. The following link will give you the list of magic numbers and you can use that in a utilty for future purpose

[image magic number](http://www.astro.keele.ac.uk/oldusers/rno/Computing/File_magic.html)